# Someone moved all questions from [mobilefirst] tag to [ibm-mobilefirst] tag and deleted the tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Someone from the Stack Overflow team must have moved all questions from [mobilefirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobilefirst) tag to the [ibm-mobilefirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-mobilefirst) and deleted the "mobilefirst" tag instead of marking it a synonym of "ibm-mobilefirst".

This in turn has removed gold-badge moderation rights from the tag which I recreated after it was removed, and now for example marking a question tagged [mobilefirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobilefirst) as a duplicate sends it to the moderation queue (which in turn means it will take for it months to be handled) instead of being acted above instantly (due to moderation rights that previously existed).

How do we fix this? Can someone at least approve the synonym request I have created for "mobilefirst" -> "ibm-mobilefirst"?

BTW, this is unlike the [worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/worklight) tag (the product's previous name that came before "mobilefirst"), which did change to "ibm-mobilefirst" and a synonym was created for it.

Comment: You seem to have the gold badge for [tag:ibm-mobilefirst] now, perhaps you were just waiting for the badge recalculation?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. What I am saying, though is that "mobilefirst" was deleted (it had a few hundred of questions that moved to "ibm-mobilefirst") instead of being made into a synonym. So now people continue to use that tag for new questions, but because it's basically a re-created tag, it can no longer be moderated.

Comment: So your problem is that people are still using the ambiguous [tag:mobilefirst] tag?

Comment: Hmm. Okay, now I see the problem. That's bad. It was a bad tag choice to begin with but now people are already "used to" use it... but because it could mean more than just this product, it probably cannot be made into a synonym.

Comment: Although in all fairness I have never seen people use it other than for "IBM MobileFirst". And I look at that tag all day all days.

Comment: There could be "mobilefirst" that is a synonym for "ibm-mobilefirst", and "mobile-first" which is about developing first for mobile.

Comment: I would be amazed if it had never been used in relation to web design. It looks like you've recreated the tag here? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37663133/revisions If it were deleted, low-rep users would not be able to recreate it.

Comment: Yes, I re-created it because the "mobilefirst" tag is documented in IBM documentation and websites in a whole lot of places, so we can't just "remove it". That is why I then also created a synonym request for it.

Comment: Different tag, but I presume the story is the same as the watson one.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. I have explained the problem here and that question **does not solve the problem** with this specific tag.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from that answer Stack Exchange has decided to use the `ibm-` prefix going forward.

Comment: Yes, that is clear and I don't have a problem with that. Previously we used "worklight" and "mobilefirst" for questions about the different versions of this product. The questions from both "worklight" and "mobilefirst" moved to "ibm-mobilefirst" and "worklight" became a synonym of "ibm-mobilefirst" - Great! Thank you!

Comment: But unlike "worklight", "mobilefirst" did not make it into a "synonym" (which I opened a request for that). That is what I am talking about in this question. That users are still directed in all places to use "mobilefirst" and "worklight". With "worklight" we now no longer have an issue, but with "mobilefirst" we do. Do you understand the problem with that?

Comment: Yes and no. It sounds like you guys need to update your links. I'm not sure your broken links justify an ambiguous tag, I would be concerned that a lot of unrelated things will use that tag. I guess SE will make or have already made that call though.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I think this is a matter to be handled by a StackOverflow staff member rather than the community. I will wait for @TimPost or someone else to chim in. I have already answered your concern in a previous comment above.

Comment: If you need to reach the staff rather than the users, use the "contact us" link below, rather than a Meta post.